# Getting to nth character from beginning of line in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I recently started using ***emacs*** for writing my programs codes. I was wondering if there was a "command" to get to the nth character **directly** from the beginning of the line without using any tricks (like repeat n times  `C-f`). I briefly went through the emacs manual but didn't find anything.

Comment: For instance to go to a specific line, one uses alt-g g. I thought using combinations of command was "a trick"..

Comment: Still no sure what you mean by "trick"  `M-g g` is pretty run-of-the-mill for a Emacs key combo.

Comment: I'm not using "trick" in a negative way, I could have said: ... without using combination of other commands.

Comment: I think you mean that you have to press two key cords? M-g and then g?  This isn't a combination of other commands, think of it as a path to get to one command.

Comment: Ok, I'm understanding Emacs better. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for n == 12

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>12</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>

or

<kbd>C-1</kbd><kbd>C-2</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that's better than what I was using previously

Comment: `C-f C-f C-f C-f C-f C-f C-f C-f C-f C-f C-f C-f`?

Comment: @Wooble: :) you must surely be joking mr. Wooble... if you want to get to character 12345678, that may be a lot of C-f's, don't you think?

Comment: `C-u 12 C-f` is not repeating `C-f` 12 times, it is passing an argument of 12 to the function `forward-char`, which is mapped to `C-f`. Subtle difference, but since this answer has been accepted, the distinction seems to be understood by the requestor.

Comment: @event_jr I previously used:    C-f C-x z z z z z z z z z        I thought of it a function taking 2 args, an integer n and a "command" that is to be applied n times.

Answer (score 3):

> I briefly went through the emacs manual but didn't find anything.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> `repeat`

Comment: yeah, there is nothing direct, but found something else (interesting for a newbie :) ) `M-n C-f`, with n being an integer.

Comment: "nothing direct"? Unless you have a very different manual to the one I'm seeing, that search would have taken you directly to the title "Numeric arguments for repeating a command N times."

Comment: I note that you did say you didn't want "repeat n times C-f" as an answer; but then you also accepted exactly that, so you can perhaps understand my confusion. I really just wanted to point out that the accepted solution can be found in the manual very easily if you use the search feature.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but one of the contributors made it clear that there are 3 ways to do that, see post from TacticalCoder. And since what I accepted was better than what I was using previously, I accepted it. Sorry for the confusion. ps: sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

*(this is too long for a comment)*

You commented you didn't want to use a combination of commands but... One of Emacs's feature is that it is very easy to "extend" it by combining functions.  There's some task you repeat often and want to automate it?  Write a function that solves your problem and bind it to a key.  Or record a macro and replay it (and bind it to a key if you want).

Now as to going to the *nth* char, the way I do it depends on what I'm after...

- Typically if I want to go to the "indentation" then I use a convenient function (which I probably got from someone on SO) bound to *C-a* which cycles between going to the beginning of the line or to the indentation:

  ```
  (defun beginning-of-line-or-indentation ()

  "move to beginning of line, or indentation"
   (interactive)
   (if (bolp)
       (back-to-indentation)
     (beginning-of-line)))
  ```
- Now if I want to go to a specific character typically I use *isearch-forward* (by default bound to *C-s*) and then type what I'm after.  I use this all the time and it's a gigantic time saver.  I see a lot of videos of people using Emacs (or something else) and moving the cursor "all the way" to a spot one could simply reach by doing C-s and then typing one or two characters and it always boggles my mind.  It of course works across multiple lines and you can search backwards by calling *isearch-backward* (by default bound to *C-r*).
- Otherwise *universal-argument* (C-u) is fine although it doesn't work if you're not at the beginning of the line.

If for some reason this is something you need to do often then it is trivial to write a function calling *beginning-of-line* then moving forward by the number of chars you want... Now of course this is Emacs so that function may already exist : )

Comment: I believe binding a self made function to a _C-a_ would be great. Could you suggest any link for tutorials?